# Specified initialization vector (IV) does not match the block size for this algorithm (Microsoft Example)

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, rijndaelmanaged

I copied the code from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/encrypting-data#asymmetric-encryption) and i changed something that's not crucial and I now get this error:

> Specified initialization vector (IV) does not match the block size for
>   this algorithm

```
byte[] publicKey = {214,46,220,83,160,73,40,39,201,155,19,202,3,11,191,178,56,
            74,90,36,248,103,18,144,170,163,145,87,54,61,34,220,222,
            207,137,149,173,14,92,120,206,222,158,28,40,24,30,16,175,
            108,128,35,230,118,40,121,113,125,216,130,11,24,90,48,194,
            240,105,44,76,34,57,249,228,125,80,38,9,136,29,117,207,139,
            168,181,85,137,126,10,126,242,120,247,121,8,100,12,201,171,
            38,226,193,180,190,117,177,87,143,242,213,11,44,180,113,93,
            106,99,179,68,175,211,164,116,64,148,226,254,172,147};

byte[] exponent = { 1, 0, 1 };

RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
RijndaelManaged rm = new RijndaelManaged();

RSAParameters rsaKeyInfo = new RSAParameters
{
    Modulus = publicKey,
    Exponent = exponent
};

rsa.ImportParameters(rsaKeyInfo);

byte[] encryptedSymmetricKey = rsa.Encrypt(rm.Key, false);
byte[] encryptedSymmetricIV = rsa.Encrypt(rm.IV, false);

CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(ms, rm.CreateEncryptor(encryptedSymmetricKey, encryptedSymmetricIV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
```

(I only added the `CryptoStream`)

Why in the microsoft article they encrypt key and iv if then throws exception of matching the size? for what purpose the encrypt this key and iv, how can i use this key and iv encrypted ?

Comment: The Key and IV are `rm.Key` and `rm.IV`. Using the encrypted Key and encrypted IV  in `rm.CreateEncryptor()` doesn't make sense. Also, encrypting the IV doesn't make sense either as it provides no security benefit but is expensive.

Comment: I dont know why is in the microsoft article

Comment: It is *not* in the Microsoft article.

Comment: //Encrypt the symmetric key and IV.  
      encryptedSymmetricKey = rsa.Encrypt(rm.Key, false);  
      encryptedSymmetricIV = rsa.Encrypt(rm.IV, false);

Comment: Yes it is, the last 2 lines of code from Asymmetric Encryption

Comment: Those lines in your code don't throw an exception, do they? The exception in thrown in the final line with the `CryptoStream`.

Comment: No they don´t, but why in the Microsoft article encrypt key and IV???